# How to adjust NetLogo source code to fold View-window of monitor window when running `inspect`

Tags: netlogo

When I try to debug a complex NetLogo model step by step, I use `user-message` to pause the program and use `inspect` to examine details.

The problem is that often the properties are too many that we have to scroll the mouse to see properties hidden. However, while `user-message` pause the program for us, all functions are halt too including scrolling and folding View option.

[image]

If I click halt button, though we can scroll the mouse to see the hidden properties, I can no longer continue to program.

I want to adjust the source code to change the size of monitor or auto-fold the View window only leaving full properties displayed whenever I use `inspect`.

Could anyone show me how to adjust the NetLogo source code to achieve the above?

Comment: That's a very creative use of `user-message`! It's a little unclear to me what your use case is - if you need this kind of debug info just to build your model, or if you want users of the model to check this information as part of a normal run. If you are just checking for debug purposes, instead of popping up an inspect window, you could either write what you're interested to a the command center with `show` or `print`, or to an `output` widget. Another option would be using `export-world` to export the whole model state, then you can open in that in an external editor to check the data.

Comment: Do you want your simulation to resume after it is paused by `user-message`, or is it sufficient to stop it and inspect its state without the ability to restart?  If the latter is okay, you can simply write a procedure to throw a runtime error, which will then allow you to peruse the View window.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks a lot for your comment! My intention is to pause (`user-message`) and inspect all properties of an agent (`inspect`), then let the program resume (click "OK" in user-message window). However, I can't view all the properties due to `user-message` freeze all functions including scrolling window while it pauses the program for me. I guess I could just use `type`, `print` to output all information I need and but I can't pause the program to view full properties of an agent, not even mention to explore and examine the entire world at a specific moment in the simulation I pause.

Comment: @Jasper but the `export-world` sounds promising, I will explore it

Comment: @Jasper I did explore it, and it is very useful! we can save the word states with `export-world` and resume it to continue iteration through `import-world` and `go` again.

Comment: @Jasper by the way here is my debugging toolkit :`if condition [ inspect agent   user-message (word "")   stop-inspecting agent `. and maybe the way to see all properties needed is just let `user-message` to output all infos I need and forget about `inspect`. Just a lot more copy and paste I guess.